# Webpage giving '404 Not Found' error after using Certbot for a subdomain

Tags: nginx, ssl, certbot

I am running Nginx on an Ubuntu server to host a website (for example, [www.c.com](http://www.c.com)).

I added another subdomain for this website (admin.c.com). This subdomain (admin.c.com) worked fine on HTTP without an SSL cert.
Then, I added a certificate for admin.c.com using certbot, similar to how I had added it earlier for [www.c.com](http://www.c.com). But, after generating the certificate for admin.c.com using certbot and adding them in the config file, I am getting a '404 Not Found' response on admin.c.com.

I have tried deleting the certificate, creating it again, and creating a subdomain with a different name to no avail.

admin.c.com works for HTTP traffic when the 443 and ssl part is removed from the config, but both http and https don't work otherwise.

I'll leave the config itself below since there are kind people who have much more experience than me :)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name c.com www.c.com admin.c.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/website/_work/C/C/admin/dist;
        index index.html index.htm;
        server_name admin.c.com;
        #error_page 404 /index.html;
        location /* {
                root /var/www/website/_work/C/C/admin/dist;
                #root /var/www/html;
                #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                client_max_body_size 200M;
        }

        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.c.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.c.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/website/_work/C/C/server/static;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name c.com www.c.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_read_timeout 90;
                proxy_redirect http://localhost:8080 https://www.c.com;

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }
        if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
        }
        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
        }
    }

    client_max_body_size 200M;
    listen [::]:443 ssl; #ipv6only=on;  managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/c.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/c.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

`nginx -t` gives the following output:

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "admin.c.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "c.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.c.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
```

I tried using Certbot to generate the ssl cerificate for an additional subdomain.
I expected the additional subdomain to work normally for both https and http traffic.
I actually got a '404 Not Found' Nginx error on the additional subdomain.

Comment: One of your location blocks starts with `location /*` which is unlikely to match anything and is probably the cause of the 404 response. Also, all those warnings need fixing. You have multiple duplicate server names listening on port 80. You need to remove the `listen 80;/listen [::]:80;` from the server blocks that do not handle http requests.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Removing the duplicate server names fixed it.